# Paytm payment gateway transaction API not working

Tags: php, android, payment-gateway, server-side, paytm

I need a help in implementing of paytm payment gateway. i am implementing the gateway in android app and i have coded it correctly and i have no errors and the sandbox keys are working fine and i am getting the responses also but then paytm sent me a file naming 'check status API.php' and said this to me i m quoting my email

> For Transaction Status API, kindly generate new checksum using MID and
>   ORDER ID and pass it on below link
>   https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus?JsonData={"MID":"MID","ORDERID":"ORDERID","CHECKSUMHASH":"CHECKSUMHASH"}
>
> Please do Url encoding for the  CHECKSUMHASH after that pass
>   checksumhash value to status API.

and i have a attachment this file

check status API.php

```
 public function PaytmTransactionStatus($order_id){

     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
     header("Expires: 0");
     require_once("lib/config_paytm.php"); 
     require_once("lib/encdec_paytm.php");

     $checkSum = "";    
     $data = array(
        "MID"=>"DIY12386817555501617",// please use your own MID.
       "ORDER_ID"=>$order_id,
     );

     $key = 'bKMfNxPPf_QdZppa';
     $checkSum =getChecksumFromArray($data, $key);// Please use your own merchant key value.


     $request=array("MID"=>'**************',
         "ORDERID"=>$order_id,"CHECKSUMHASH"=>$checkSum);

     $JsonData =json_encode($request);
     $postData = 'JsonData='.urlencode($JsonData);
     $url = "https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus";

     $HEADER[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
     $HEADER[] = "Accept: application/json";

     $args['HEADER'] = $HEADER;  
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);   
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $args['HEADER']);
     $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

     return json_decode($server_output,true);
```

i modified MID and merchant key with mine and uploaded it to server but the api is not working it is returning me whole code written in the browser but it should return json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research work finally, i wrote something that works fine

```
<?php

     if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

     $order_id = $_POST['order_id'];


     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
     header("Expires: 0");

       require_once("./lib/config_paytm.php");
     require_once("./lib/encdec_paytm.php");

     $checkSum = "";   

     $paramList = array();
     $paramList["MID"] = 'YOUR MID'; //Provided by Paytm
     $paramList["ORDER_ID"] = $order_id; //unique OrderId for every request

    $checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,"YOUR KEY");
    $paramList["CHECKSUMHASH"] = urlencode($checkSum);

    $data_string = 'JsonData='.json_encode($paramList);



    $ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
    $url = "https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus"; // 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string); 
   post
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); /
   format
  $headers = array();
  $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   $output = curl_exec ($ch); // execute
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  echo $output;

   return json_decode($output, true);

     }

     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the URL for staging and production URLs are different.

**Staging** 
`$url = 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/merchant-status/getTxnStatus';`

**LIVE** 
`$url = 'https://securegw.paytm.in/merchant-status/getTxnStatus';`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to check status:

```
<?php
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// following files need to be included
$raw_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

function pkcs5_unpad_e($text) {
    $pad = ord($text{strlen($text) - 1});
    if ($pad > strlen($text))
        return false;
    return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
}
function pkcs5_pad_e($text, $blocksize) {
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}
function encrypt_e($input, $ky) {
    $key = $ky;
    $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'cbc');
    $input = pkcs5_pad_e($input, $size);
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', 'cbc', '');
    $iv = "@@@@&&&&####$$$$";
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    $data = base64_encode($data);
    return $data;
}
function getChecksumFromArray($arrayList, $key, $sort=1) {
    if ($sort != 0) {
        ksort($arrayList);
    }
    $str = getArray2Str($arrayList);
    $salt = generateSalt_e(4);
    $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;
    $hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
    $hashString = $hash . $salt;
    $checksum = encrypt_e($hashString, $key);
    return $checksum;
}
function getArray2Str($arrayList) {
    $paramStr = "";
    $flag = 1;
    foreach ($arrayList as $key => $value) {
        if ($flag) {
            $paramStr .= checkString_e($value);
            $flag = 0;
        } else {
            $paramStr .= "|" . checkString_e($value);
        }
    }
    return $paramStr;
}
//Gaurav check
function generateSalt_e($length) {
    $random = "";
    srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);

    $data = "AbcDE123IJKLMN67QRSTUVWXYZ";
    $data .= "aBCdefghijklmn123opq45rs67tuv89wxyz";
    $data .= "0FGH45OP89";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $random .= substr($data, (rand() % (strlen($data))), 1);
    }

    return $random;
}
function checkString_e($value) {
    $myvalue = ltrim($value);
    $myvalue = rtrim($myvalue);
    if ($myvalue == 'null')
        $myvalue = '';
    return $myvalue;
}


//test code

$checkSum = "";

$paramList = array();
$paramList["MID"] = 'your_MID';
$paramList["ORDERID"] = $raw_data["order_id"];

//Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
$checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,"your_key");
 $check=urlencode($checkSum);  
 $paramList["CHECKSUMHASH"]=$check;
$data_string = json_encode($paramList); 

$ch = curl_init();                    // initiate curl
$url = "https://secure.paytm.in/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus?JsonData=".$data_string; // where you want to post data

$headers = array('Content-Type:application/json');

$ch = curl_init();  // initiate curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);  // tell curl you want to post something
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_string); // define what you want to post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return the output in string format
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$output = curl_exec ($ch); // execute
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
//print_r($info)."<br />";
echo ($output);
?>
```

Comment: {"ErrorCode":"CMER-IP101","ErrorMsg":"Internal Processing Error"}       the response i m getting  after running the script and i have changes the MID with mine in the code don't we need to change the key is well but i can not find the key in code ...

Comment: have you edited your MID and Secret key in the code?

Comment: //Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
$checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,"your_key");

Comment: yes now i update the key with mine but the error remains same

Comment: This is what worked for me. Do you have library files config_paytm.php and encdec_paytm.php ?

Comment: have you added your secret key in those files?

Comment: i have changed it in config_paytm file but i am not finding any place to do so in the other file encdec_paytm.php  , the response remains same

Comment: Try contacting paytm support team.

Comment: yes , let me contact them, but any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change
**Staging url**

```php
$url = "https://securegw-tage.paytm.in/order/status";
```

To

**Production**

```php
$url = "https://securegw.paytm.in/order/status";
```